# jeditable to update database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jeditable

I need the jeditable plugin to update the ProductName in the database when it gets edited. As of right now the ProductName only updates on the page. I didn't install this plugin so I'm not familiar with how it works or the code behind it all. I am just looking for some help, I understand that the code might look funky, but I didn't write any of this. Thanks

ProductPage.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// EDIT PRODUCT NAME

$('.productName.edit').editable(function (value, settings) {
    var ProductID = $('input#body_ProductID').val();
    var result = SubmitProductName(ProductID, value);
    return (value);
}, {
    width: '350',
    submit: 'Save Changes',
    cancel: 'Cancel',
    onBlur: 'ignore'
});


// this makes the call to the webservice to update the product name
```

**The problem is right here in the SubmitProductName function. After putting alerts in the javascript, I found out that the UpdateProductName url was never getting hit**

```
function SubmitProductName(ProductID, NewName) {
    var result;
    **$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: '{ "ProductID" : "' + ProductID + '", "UpdateText" : "' + NewName + '"}',
        url: '../WebService.asmx/UpdateProductName',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {
            result = json.d;
        },**
        error: function (e) {
            result = "error";
        }
    });

}  
});
```

WebService.vb

```
'Updates a product and returns the new product name
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function UpdateProductName(ProductID As String, UpdateText As String) As String
    Dim sqlUpdate As String = "UPDATE Product SET ProductName = '" & UpdateText & "' WHERE ProductID = " & ProductID
    Dim sqlResults As String = "SELECT ProductName FROM Product WHERE ProductID = " & ProductID

    'Create sql connection object
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Server=off-db1;uid=productsDB_admin;pwd=*******;database=Products")

    'Open SQL connection
    sqlConn.Open()

    'SQL Statement to get CategoryIDs and Names of all subcategories
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, sqlConn)

    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim cmdResults As New SqlCommand(sqlResults, sqlConn)
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = cmdResults.ExecuteReader()
    Dim results As String = Nothing

    While myReader.Read
        results = myReader(0)
    End While

    myReader.Close()
    sqlConn.Close()

    Return results

End Function
```

jeditable.js

```
(function($) {

$.fn.editable = function(target, options) {

    if ('disable' == target) {
        $(this).data('disabled.editable', true);
        return;
    }
    if ('enable' == target) {
        $(this).data('disabled.editable', false);
        return;
    }
    if ('destroy' == target) {
        $(this)
            .unbind($(this).data('event.editable'))
            .removeData('disabled.editable')
            .removeData('event.editable');
        return;
    }

    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.editable.defaults, {target:target}, options);

    /* setup some functions */
    var plugin   = $.editable.types[settings.type].plugin || function() { };
    var submit   = $.editable.types[settings.type].submit || function() { };
    var buttons  = $.editable.types[settings.type].buttons 
                || $.editable.types['defaults'].buttons;
    var content  = $.editable.types[settings.type].content 
                || $.editable.types['defaults'].content;
    var element  = $.editable.types[settings.type].element 
                || $.editable.types['defaults'].element;
    var reset    = $.editable.types[settings.type].reset 
                || $.editable.types['defaults'].reset;
    var callback = settings.callback || function() { };
    var onedit   = settings.onedit   || function() { }; 
    var onsubmit = settings.onsubmit || function() { };
    var onreset  = settings.onreset  || function() { };
    var onerror  = settings.onerror  || reset;

    /* show tooltip */
    if (settings.tooltip) {
        $(this).attr('title', settings.tooltip);
    }

    settings.autowidth  = 'auto' == settings.width;
    settings.autoheight = 'auto' == settings.height;

    return this.each(function() {

        /* save this to self because this changes when scope changes */
        var self = this;  

        /* inlined block elements lose their width and height after first edit */
        /* save them for later use as workaround */
        var savedwidth  = $(self).width();
        var savedheight = $(self).height();
        /* save so it can be later used by $.editable('destroy') */
        $(this).data('event.editable', settings.event);

        /* if element is empty add something clickable (if requested) */
        if (!$.trim($(this).html())) {
            $(this).html(settings.placeholder);
        }

        $(this).bind(settings.event, function(e) {

            /* abort if disabled for this element */
            if (true === $(this).data('disabled.editable')) {
                return;
            }

            /* prevent throwing an exeption if edit field is clicked again */
            if (self.editing) {
                return;
            }

            /* abort if onedit hook returns false */
            if (false === onedit.apply(this, [settings, self])) {
               return;
            }

            /* prevent default action and bubbling */
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            /* remove tooltip */
            if (settings.tooltip) {
                $(self).removeAttr('title');
            }

            /* figure out how wide and tall we are, saved width and height */
            /* are workaround for http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2190 */
            if (0 == $(self).width()) {
                //$(self).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                settings.width  = savedwidth;
                settings.height = savedheight;
            } else {
                if (settings.width != 'none') {
                    settings.width = 
                        settings.autowidth ? $(self).width()  : settings.width;
                }
                if (settings.height != 'none') {
                    settings.height = 
                        settings.autoheight ? $(self).height() : settings.height;
                }
            }
            //$(this).css('visibility', '');

            /* remove placeholder text, replace is here because of IE */
            if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().replace(/(;|")/g, '') == 
                settings.placeholder.toLowerCase().replace(/(;|")/g, '')) {
                    $(this).html('');
            }

            self.editing    = true;
            self.revert     = $(self).html();
            $(self).html('');

            /* create the form object */
            var form = $('<form />');

            /* apply css or style or both */
            if (settings.cssclass) {
                if ('inherit' == settings.cssclass) {
                    form.attr('class', $(self).attr('class'));
                } else {
                    form.attr('class', settings.cssclass);
                }
            }

            if (settings.style) {
                if ('inherit' == settings.style) {
                    form.attr('style', $(self).attr('style'));
                    /* IE needs the second line or display wont be inherited */
                    form.css('display', $(self).css('display'));                
                } else {
                    form.attr('style', settings.style);
                }
            }

            /* add main input element to form and store it in input */
            var input = element.apply(form, [settings, self]);

            /* set input content via POST, GET, given data or existing value */
            var input_content;

            if (settings.loadurl) {
                var t = setTimeout(function() {
                    input.disabled = true;
                    content.apply(form, [settings.loadtext, settings, self]);
                }, 100);

                var loaddata = {};
                loaddata[settings.id] = self.id;
                if ($.isFunction(settings.loaddata)) {
                    $.extend(loaddata, settings.loaddata.apply(self, [self.revert, 
                    settings]));
                } else {
                    $.extend(loaddata, settings.loaddata);
                }
                $.ajax({
                   type : settings.loadtype,
                   url  : settings.loadurl,
                   data : loaddata,
                   async : false,
                   success: function(result) {
                      window.clearTimeout(t);
                      input_content = result;
                      input.disabled = false;
                   }
                });
            } else if (settings.data) {
                input_content = settings.data;
                if ($.isFunction(settings.data)) {
                    input_content = settings.data.apply(self, [self.revert, settings]);
                }
            } else {
                input_content = self.revert; 
            }
            content.apply(form, [input_content, settings, self]);

            input.attr('name', settings.name);

            /* add buttons to the form */
            buttons.apply(form, [settings, self]);

            /* add created form to self */
            $(self).append(form);

            /* attach 3rd party plugin if requested */
            plugin.apply(form, [settings, self]);

            /* focus to first visible form element */
            $(':input:visible:enabled:first', form).focus();

            /* highlight input contents when requested */
            if (settings.select) {
                input.select();
            }

            /* discard changes if pressing esc */
            input.keydown(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //self.reset();
                    reset.apply(form, [settings, self]);
                }
            });

            /* discard, submit or nothing with changes when clicking outside */
            /* do nothing is usable when navigating with tab */
            var t;
            if ('cancel' == settings.onblur) {
                input.blur(function(e) {
                    /* prevent canceling if submit was clicked */
                    t = setTimeout(function() {
                        reset.apply(form, [settings, self]);
                    }, 500);
                });
            } else if ('submit' == settings.onblur) {
                input.blur(function(e) {
                    /* prevent double submit if submit was clicked */
                    t = setTimeout(function() {
                        form.submit();
                    }, 200);
                });
            } else if ($.isFunction(settings.onblur)) {
                input.blur(function(e) {
                    settings.onblur.apply(self, [input.val(), settings]);
                });
            } else {
                input.blur(function(e) {
                  /* TODO: maybe something here */
                });
            }

            form.submit(function(e) {

                if (t) { 
                    clearTimeout(t);
                }

                /* do no submit */
                e.preventDefault(); 

                /* call before submit hook. */
                /* if it returns false abort submitting */                    
                if (false !== onsubmit.apply(form, [settings, self])) { 
                    /* custom inputs call before submit hook. */
                    /* if it returns false abort submitting */
                    if (false !== submit.apply(form, [settings, self])) { 

                      /* check if given target is function */
                      if ($.isFunction(settings.target)) {
                          var str = settings.target.apply(self, [input.val(), 
                          settings]);
                          $(self).html(str);
                          self.editing = false;
                          callback.apply(self, [self.innerHTML, settings]);
                          /* TODO: this is not dry */                              
                          if (!$.trim($(self).html())) {
                              $(self).html(settings.placeholder);
                          }
                      } else {
                          /* add edited content and id of edited element to POST */
                          var submitdata = {};
                          submitdata[settings.name] = input.val();
                          submitdata[settings.id] = self.id;
                          /* add extra data to be POST:ed */
                          if ($.isFunction(settings.submitdata)) {
                              $.extend(submitdata, settings.submitdata.apply(self, 
                              [self.revert, settings]));
                          } else {
                              $.extend(submitdata, settings.submitdata);
                          }

                          /* quick and dirty PUT support */
                          if ('PUT' == settings.method) {
                              submitdata['_method'] = 'put';
                          }

                          /* show the saving indicator */
                          $(self).html(settings.indicator);

                          /* defaults for ajaxoptions */
                          var ajaxoptions = {
                              type    : 'POST',
                              data    : submitdata,
                              dataType: 'html',
                              url     : settings.target,
                              success : function(result, status) {
                                  if (ajaxoptions.dataType == 'html') {
                                    $(self).html(result);
                                  }
                                  self.editing = false;
                                  callback.apply(self, [result, settings]);
                                  if (!$.trim($(self).html())) {
                                      $(self).html(settings.placeholder);
                                  }
                              },
                              error   : function(xhr, status, error) {
                                  onerror.apply(form, [settings, self, xhr]);
                              }
                          };

                          /* override with what is given in settings.ajaxoptions */
                          $.extend(ajaxoptions, settings.ajaxoptions);   
                          $.ajax(ajaxoptions);          

                        }
                    }
                }

                /* show tooltip again */
                $(self).attr('title', settings.tooltip);

                return false;
            });
        });

        /* privileged methods */
        this.reset = function(form) {
            /* prevent calling reset twice when blurring */
            if (this.editing) {
                /* before reset hook, if it returns false abort reseting */
                if (false !== onreset.apply(form, [settings, self])) { 
                    $(self).html(self.revert);
                    self.editing   = false;
                    if (!$.trim($(self).html())) {
                        $(self).html(settings.placeholder);
                    }
                    /* show tooltip again */
                    if (settings.tooltip) {
                        $(self).attr('title', settings.tooltip);                
                    }
                }                    
            }
        };            
    });

};


$.editable = {
    types: {
        defaults: {
            element : function(settings, original) {
                var input = $('<input type="hidden"></input>');                
                $(this).append(input);
                return(input);
            },
            content : function(string, settings, original) {
                $(':input:first', this).val(string);
            },
            reset : function(settings, original) {
              original.reset(this);
            },
            buttons : function(settings, original) {
                var form = this;
                if (settings.submit) {
                    /* if given html string use that */
                    if (settings.submit.match(/>$/)) {
                        var submit = $(settings.submit).click(function() {
                            if (submit.attr("type") != "submit") {
                                form.submit();
                            }
                        });
                    /* otherwise use button with given string as text */
                    } else {
                        var submit = $('<button type="submit" />');
                        submit.html(settings.submit);                            
                    }
                    $(this).append(submit);
                }
                if (settings.cancel) {
                    /* if given html string use that */
                    if (settings.cancel.match(/>$/)) {
                        var cancel = $(settings.cancel);
                    /* otherwise use button with given string as text */
                    } else {
                        var cancel = $('<button type="cancel" />');
                        cancel.html(settings.cancel);
                    }
                    $(this).append(cancel);

                    $(cancel).click(function(event) {
                        //original.reset();
                        if ($.isFunction($.editable.types[settings.type].reset)) {
                            var reset = $.editable.types[settings.type].reset;                                                                
                        } else {
                            var reset = $.editable.types['defaults'].reset;                                
                        }
                        reset.apply(form, [settings, original]);
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        text: {
            element : function(settings, original) {
                var input = $('<input />');
                if (settings.width  != 'none') { input.width(settings.width);  }
                if (settings.height != 'none') { input.height(settings.height); }
                /* https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=236791 */
                //input[0].setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
                input.attr('autocomplete','off');
                $(this).append(input);
                return(input);
            }
        },
        textarea: {
            element : function(settings, original) {
                var textarea = $('<textarea />');
                if (settings.rows) {
                    textarea.attr('rows', settings.rows);
                } else if (settings.height != "none") {
                    textarea.height(settings.height);
                }
                if (settings.cols) {
                    textarea.attr('cols', settings.cols);
                } else if (settings.width != "none") {
                    textarea.width(settings.width);
                }
                $(this).append(textarea);
                return(textarea);
            }
        },
        select: {
           element : function(settings, original) {
                var select = $('<select />');
                $(this).append(select);
                return(select);
            },
            content : function(data, settings, original) {
                /* If it is string assume it is json. */
                if (String == data.constructor) {      
                    eval ('var json = ' + data);
                } else {
                /* Otherwise assume it is a hash already. */
                    var json = data;
                }
                for (var key in json) {
                    if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ('selected' == key) {
                        continue;
                    } 
                    var option = $('<option />').val(key).append(json[key]);
                    $('select', this).append(option);    
                }                    
                /* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */ 
                $('select', this).children().each(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() == json['selected'] || 
                        $(this).text() == $.trim(original.revert)) {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },

    /* Add new input type */
    addInputType: function(name, input) {
        $.editable.types[name] = input;
    }
};

// publicly accessible defaults
$.fn.editable.defaults = {
    name       : 'value',
    id         : 'id',
    type       : 'text',
    width      : 'auto',
    height     : 'auto',
    event      : 'click.editable',
    onblur     : 'cancel',
    loadtype   : 'GET',
    loadtext   : 'Loading...',
    placeholder: 'No description.',
    loaddata   : {},
    submitdata : {},
    ajaxoptions: {}
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I still have not figured this out. Help would be much appreciated. I am getting toward the end of my project and need to tie up all the loose ends, such as this one.

Comment: is your UpdateProductName function located in the WebService.asmx file?  Is this function being hit by the jQuery post method?

Comment: UpdateProductName is in the WebService.vb file. I don't know if the jQuery post is doing anything because I'm not certain I understand the jQuery at all. I can edit the original post with the jQuery but the file is enormous.

Comment: you can put a breakpoint on the UpdateProductName function and see if it gets hit.  If you want to see if the javascript is firing properly you can debug it using firebug or just throw an alert before $.ajax and one in success and error and see what is actually getting executed.  That should at least get you started.

Comment: I put the breakpoint there, but when I edit the text the breakpoint stays red. Shouldn't it turn yellow once it's been reached? So that means that UpdateProductName is not getting called, right?

Comment: yup, so at least you know that isn't being hit, next you'll want to test your ajax call by putting some alerts in your javascript (not best way but easiest right now).  Put one before your ajax call alert('pre ajax');, put one in your success alert('success'); and error alert('error');.   We know the success won't fire but we'll put it there just in case something crazy is going on.

Comment: other question i should've asked is... has this ever worked before?

Comment: @ajrawson I got the alert I put in before the ajax but I didn't get the one in success.

Comment: No, it's never worked. The guy that wrote the site left this plugin non-functional so I don't know what I'm supposed to do. Non-functional means that the text will edit, it just won't reflect changes in the database.

Comment: Just realized you said the WebService had an extension of vb, and not of a normal web service, wondering if this is the problem?  It should be asmx.

Comment: Oh yeah there is an asmx file, but it points to a vb file in the App_Code folder. Every time I create a new webservice it makes an asmx file and a vb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running some diagnostics on your ajax request using something like Firebug. This should give you an idea of what type of issues the request is running into.

My first guess would be url:

```
'../WebService.asmx/UpdateProductName'
```

is either one looking in the wrong directory, or two is getting denied by some authentication you have setup in your application.

You could do something like [this](http://ajrawson.com/display-jquery-ajax-error-information) to display error information about your ajax request on your screen

Comment: Added one more ../ to that url to get back to parent and it was able to find the WebService. Thanks for all your help! I'll be using Firebug a lot more now that I know how to use it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the backend to do the DB update.  Javascript is run on the client and can't possibly do it itself.  In ASP.NET, you'd usually write a Web Service (.svc or .asmx) that receives the POST jEditable can send to do the database update.

When you call .editable() on an element, the first argument is the URL it should post the result to -- that should point to your web service.

From jEditable's web page:

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
 });

In that case, save.php is the PHP web service... substitute your own.